# Is it possible to start a PyQt5 media player on a different thread and still interact with it?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading, qmediaplayer

For a project I'm building a PyQt5 media player. I want to be able to play new video's in my media player by enqueueing a new url to a shared queue between my main thread and my media player. The code I'm using for now is the following:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

import threading
import time

class MediaPlayer(QWidget, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, url_first_media):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Instantiate queue
        self.queue = queue

        # Create URL
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(url_first_media)

        # Set window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")

        # Init UI
        self.__init_ui()

        # Play initial video
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(self.url))
        self.media_player.play()

        # Show maximized
        self.showMaximized()

    def __init_ui(self):
        INITIALIZE UI, left out to not make this code block too bulky.

    def run(self):
        self.__process_data()

    def __process_data(self):
        terminate = False
        while not terminate:
            if not self.queue.empty():
                url, terminate = self.queue.get()
                self.__change_video(url)
            
            time.sleep(1)

    def __change_video(self, video_url):
        # Create URL object
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(video_url)

        # Change playing video
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(self.url))

        # Play new video
        self.media_player.play()
```

My main thread is from another class called Environment, the code for that one is the following.

```
from media_player import MediaPlayer

import queue

class Environment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue(5)
        self.media_player = MediaPlayer(self.queue, "path")
        self.__start_media_player()

    def __start_media_player(self):
        self.media_player.start()
```

So for now, what I think is working correctly is just starting the thread. Obviously the media player isn't showing since I'm not showing it like the PyQt5 documentation suggests. The code they suggest adapted to my class is the following.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from media_player import MediaPlayer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MediaPlayer(queue, "path_to_video")
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I am not sure where to put this code into my current structure to make this work. I wanted to put it after **self.__process_data()** in **run()** but I'm afraid this won't work since there is a while loop in front of it. Something else I wanted to try is to put it after starting my thread in **Environment**. I'm also afraid this won't work since I guess the loop from showing the media player will lock up my main thread. Is there any solution to this or am I looking at it wrong?

The main thing what I want to achieve is changing the playing video in my media_player by calling for example **__change_video()**. I also looked into working threads from PyQt5 but I don't want my environment thread to be destroyed since I need it for other things to interact with (so I cannot keep deleting / initializing an **Environment** object). I'm quite new to multithreading and PyQt5 so any help / advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve nor why you're using threading, but one thing is certain: widgets are ***NOT*** thread safe, can *not* be created or accessed from external threads, and you cannot subclass from both `Thread` and QWidget (well, you *could*, but it doesn't make any sense).

Comment: I have to be able to change the playing video in the media player without using a file browser and a play button, that's what I'd like to achieve. In other words I want to be able to change the playing video by for example calling environment.change_video("path to new video") @musicamante

Comment: Change *when*? From *what*?

Comment: So the whole project is about training an AI agent to distinguish between "scary" videos and "relaxing" videos. To do this I should be able to display a new video in the mediaplayer each 5 seconds. But which next video to play is not being able to be hardcoded since the agent should find out what video is good to play through trial and error. So what I originally should be able to do is expose some method in the mediaplayer to the agent which the agent can use to change the currently playing video. Is it any clearer?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this is a better approach @musicamante. Closing the media player after the video has stopped playing (I cut all my videos to 5 seconds so this shouldn't be too much of a problem, I think?). When it stops playing I can create a new instance in **Environment** with another initial url. So instead of changing it while the window stays open, I would open and close new media players throughout the process. Does this make more sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Connect the [`mediaStatusChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged) signal, check if the argument is `EndOfMedia` and just call [`setMedia()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia) with the new url.

Comment: But will I be able to set the media from outside the MediaPlayer class?

Comment: The QMediaPlayer instance is available with the `media_player` attribute. So, if you have a `MediaPlayer` instance named `self.myMediaPlayer` it would be something like `self.myMediaPlayer.media_player.setMedia(...)`. I suggest you to do some research on classes, instances, attributes and methods in python.

Comment: I know how classes etc. work, I meant it more in a way that will I be able to call **setMedia()** whilst the media player is running? Because the loop that I use to run the player blocks execution from all the code happening after it.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. You can **not** use threading for *ANY* QWidget, and you can **not** use any while loop in the main thread. The "queue" must be implemented externally and you will **only** communicate with the media player and/or the QApplication using (possibly, custom) signals. And that's assuming that you *actually* need threading, and I suspect that you actually don't, if you properly use signals: the `mediaStatusChanged` could probably be connected to a function that "decides" what is the next media to reproduce, and it will eventually call `setMedia()`.